# aggregating metrics data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to pull report data out of a realtime metrics system inspired by the [NYC MUG/SimpleReach](https://speakerdeck.com/mongodb/schemas-for-real-time-analytics-with-nodejs-eric-lubow-and-russell-bradberry-simplereach) schema, and maybe my mind is still stuck in SQL mode.

The data is stored in a document like so...

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5209683b915288435894cb8b"),
"account_id": 922,
"project_id": 22492,
"stats": {
    "2009": {
        "04": {
            "17": {
                "10": {
                    "sum": {
                        "impressions": 11
                    }
                },
                "11": {
                    "sum": {
                        "impressions": 603
                    }
                },
             },
         },
     },
 }}
```

and I've been trying different variations of the aggregation pipeline with no success.

```
db.metrics.aggregate({
$match: {
    'project_id':22492
}}, {
$group: {
    _id: "$project_id",
    'impressions': {

         //This works, but doesn't sum up the data...
         $sum: '$stats.2009.04.17.10.sum.impressions'

         /* none of these work.
         $sum: ['$stats.2009.04.17.10.sum.impressions',          
              '$stats.2009.04.17.11.sum.impressions']

         $sum: {'$stats.2009.04.17.10.sum.impressions',          
              '$stats.2009.04.17.11.sum.impressions'}

        $sum: '$stats.2009.04.17.10.sum.impressions',          
              '$stats.2009.04.17.11.sum.impressions'
        */
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

(ps. does anyone have any ideas on how to do date range searches using this document schema? )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$group` is designed to be applied to many documents, but here we only have one matched document.
Instead, [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)  could be used to sum up specific fields, like this:

```
db.metrics.aggregate(
{ $match: {
    'project_id':22492
  }
},
{ $project: {
    'impressions': {
      $add: [
        '$stats.2009.04.17.10.sum.impressions',
        '$stats.2009.04.17.11.sum.impressions'
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

I don't think there is an elegant way to do date range searches with this schema, because MongoDB operations/predictions are designed to be applied on values, rather than keys in a document. If I understand correctly, the most interesting point in the slides you mentioned is to cache/pre-aggregate metrics when updating. That's a good idea, but could be implemented with another schema. For example, using date and time with indexes, which are supported by MongoDB, might be a good choice for range searches. Even aggregation framework supports [data operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operator-date/), giving more flexibility.